# jq parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to run a simple jq in a shell script block that basically returns array of s3 buckets with specific tags and I am able to get it working for the most part except this error.

Here is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
s3_buckets_with_cache() {
  local S3CACHE JSONBUCKETS bucketwithtags tags
  #S3CACHE="${DIR_CACHE}/s3buckets.json"
  S3CACHE="s3buckets.json"
  if [[ ! -f ${S3CACHE} ]]; then
    JSONBUCKETS='{"buckets":[]}'
    IFS=$'\n'
    for bucket in $(aws s3api list-buckets --no-verify-ssl --query 'Buckets[?contains(Name, `.logs.`) == `true`]' | jq '.[].Name' -r); do
      echo $bucket
      tags=$(aws s3api get-bucket-tagging --no-verify-ssl --bucket "${bucket}" | jq '.TagSet[] | select(.Key == "mark_for_delete" or .Key == "expiration_date")')
      echo ${tags}
      # shellcheck disable=SC2181
      [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]] && continue
      tags=$(echo "${tags}" | jq -c '{(.Key): .Value}' | jq --slurp .)
      echo ${tags}
      [[ "${tags}" == "[]" ]] && continue
      bucketwithtags="{\"bucket\": \"${bucket}\", \"tags\" : ${tags} }"
      JSONBUCKETS=$(echo "${JSONBUCKETS}" | jq ".buckets += [${bucketwithtags}]")
      #echo $JSONBUCKETS
    done
    echo "${JSONBUCKETS}" >"${S3CACHE}"
  else
      echo "file present"
  fi
  cat "${S3CACHE}"
  }



s3_buckets_with_cache | jq '.buckets[].bucket'
```

calling `s3_buckets_with_cache` without the jq returns

```
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "bucket": "abc.logs.test",
      "tags": [
        {
          "expiration_date": "12-06-2022"
        },
        {
          "mark_for_delete": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "bucket": "bcd.logs.test",
      "tags": [
        {
          "mark_for_delete": "true"
        },
        {
          "expiration_date": "08-15-2022"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`s3_buckets_with_cache | jq '.buckets[].bucket'` is breaking the logic. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The provided JSON fed into `jq '.buckets[].bucket'` should work [just fine](https://jqplay.org/s/KSP6o7xzyxL).

Comment: it does. But not from the script.

Comment: Add `tee` in the middle. That is, `s3_buckets_with_cache | tee outfile.json | jq ...` and then add `outfile.json` here, so we're seeing it _as it goes through the pipeline_ vs how it gets generated for terminal consumption.

Comment: BTW, (1) http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend; (2) all-caps variable names are reserved -- applications should use lower-case names for variables that aren't intended to reflect or modify shell behavior (IFS, PATH, etc. are cases where you're setting them explicitly to modify the shell's behavior; I don't see any other names in your script that applies to).

Comment: Try `s3_buckets_with_cache | cat` to force non-tty output. Perhaps the binary is detecting the pipe and behaving differently in that case?

Comment: Strangely, after using `s3_buckets_with_cache | tee outfile.json | jq '.buckets[].bucket'` I am seeing no errors. It generates the output correctly. What could be happening here?

Comment: @fledgling intermediate/temporary error of S3? Network outage? Or does it start failing again if you remove `tee`? I think this was a temporary issue.

Comment: It still fails if I remove `tee`

Comment: @fledgling note that your function is echoing lots of stuff that is definitely not JSON. If you hit one of those echos, you cannot pipe the output to `jq`. (buckets, tags, "file present")

Comment: (for echo operations meant for human consumption as opposed to those writing JSON, you should use `>&2` to send the content to stderr, which is where "diagnostic output" belongs).